# Hadoop installation results in "Permission denied"

Tags: hadoop, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows subsystem Ubuntu and set preliminary key gen, ssh installations and all. When I try to download Hadoop I get this error.

```
--2018-03-13 16:29:43--  http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.0.0/hadoop-3.0.0.tar.gz
Resolving apache.mirrors.tds.net (apache.mirrors.tds.net)... 216.165.129.134
Connecting to apache.mirrors.tds.net (apache.mirrors.tds.net)|216.165.129.134|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 306392917 (292M) [application/x-gzip]
hadoop-3.0.0.tar.gz: Permission denied

Cannot write to ‘hadoop-3.0.0.tar.gz’ (Success).
```

Comment: What is a "Windows subsystem Ubuntu"? Readers will probably need more details than have been provided in order to help you.

Comment: As an aside, you do not need to add "Please help me" to all of your questions. Native English speakers may interpret this as a form of begging and pleading, which may irritate volunteers sufficiently to skip your question. Keep questions succinct if you can!

Comment: Related to [your next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262433/how-to-access-ubuntu-usr-local-in-windows).

Comment: (Answering my own question, this is the [Ubuntu Bash project for Windows](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/)).